# creating Price object in stripe payment with customized interval

Tags: stripe-payments

I can create price in stripe using, for month and year:

```
price1 = stripe.Price.create(
    product=product.stripe_id,
    unit_amount=1000,
    currency='usd',
    recurring={
        'interval': 'month',
    },
)

price4 = stripe.Price.create(
    product=product.stripe_id,
    unit_amount=12000,
    currency='usd',
    recurring={
        'interval': 'year',
    },
)
```

I was wondering how can I create for 3 month and 6 month. they are obviously available, for creating from interface:
[image]

however if I use "6month" or "6-month" or ...
it gives the following error:

```
Invalid recurring[interval]: must be one of month, year, week, or day
```

any ide how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `recurring.interval_count` with `recurring.interval` to specify the number of intervals between subscription billings. For example, you could set `interval=month` and `interval_count=6` to get a price that bills every 6 months. In your code, that would look like this:

```
price1 = stripe.Price.create(
    product=product.stripe_id,
    unit_amount=1000,
    currency='usd',
    recurring={
        'interval': 'month',
        'interval_count': 6
    },
)
```

Here's the documentation for `recurring.interval_count`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create?lang=cli#create_price-recurring-interval_count